# the value of local variable is not used

Tags: java

I wrote a small program to check the given movie name exist in a folder. I am getting the warning on eclipse "the value of local variable is not used"

Here is the main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean movie_exist=false;

        System.out.println("Hellow world!");

        try{

        FileWriting newfolrder = new FileWriting("H:\\breakinbad2\\Breaking Bad Season 2 Complete 720p.BRrip.Sujaidr");
        //movie_exist=newfolrder.checkfilesname("Movie name");
        System.out.println(newfolrder.checkMovieExist("Breaking Bad"));
        movie_exist = newfolrder.checkMovieExist("Breaking Bad");

        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            System.out.println("Exception is :"+ e);
        }

    }
```

I get the warning against this variable declaration

```
boolean movie_exist=false;
```

I have assign a value to the variable.

```
movie_exist = newfolrder.checkMovieExist("Breaking Bad");
```

Why do I get this warning?

Comment: the `false` value assigned to `movie_exist` is never used before it is overwritten.

Comment: It completely ethical and legal as long as you have permission from the rights holder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would happen if you completely removed the use of `movie_exist`? Nothing, your application would work exactly the same way.

You've never used `movie_exist` as an expression that resolves to a value, so it warns you about it so that you may remove it or start using it.

Answer (score 3):

Because you assigned and re-assigned the variable but never actually used it anywhere.

So if you removed this variable definition it wouldn't affect the code. You have to use it in an if condition, method call, etc. in order for the warning to disappear